# Remove the use of eval function from code

Tags: javascript, eval, prototype-programming

One of my favorite pieces of code to use is:

```
if (!(eval("this instanceof "+arguments.callee.name)))
  return eval("new "+arguments.callee.name+"(...arguments)");
```

This piece of code allows function prototypes to create themselves when set like getting the result of themselves as a regular function. (Removes the requirement to type 'new' for function prototypes)

However, that it uses eval.
Is there any way to remove eval from it?

Also, is there a way to shorten it further?

Comment: Why can't you just type out the callee function name?

Comment: Why do you want it to be so dynamic?

Comment: I want it to be dynamic because I like pasting it where I think it would make function declarations prettier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there's no need for `eval` there. Here's how you'd do it in modern environments (ES2015+):

```
function Example(...args) {
    if (!new.target) {
        return new Example(...args);
    }
    // ...use `args` here, possibly destructuring to local meaningful names e.g.:
    const [first, second] = args;
    // ...
}
```

That avoids using `eval`, the `arguments` pseudo-array, and also `arguments.callee`, which should never be used and which is disallowed in strict mode. (Strict mode is the default in modules and classes and will be the default in any further new scopes added to the language.)

You could keep using the `arguments` pseudo array if you like:

```
function Example(first, second) {
    if (!new.target) {
        return new Example(...arguments);
    }
    // ...
}
```

---

FWIW, I strongly recommend **not** making a function dual-use like that. Instead, consider using `class` syntax and a `create` function for when you don't want to use `new`:

```
class Example {
    constructor(biz, baz) {
        // ...
    }
    static create(...args) {
        return new Example(...args); // Or `return new this(...args);` or a couple of other choices.
    }
}
```

If you try to do `Example(1, 2)`, an error is automatically thrown because `class` constructors can't be called as though they were normal functions. You can avoid `new` by using `Example.create(1, 2)` instead.

The version of `create` that uses `this` avoids explicitly naming the constructor:

```
    static create(...args) {
        return new this(...args);
    }
```

That works because when you do `Example.create(1, 2)`, during the call to `create` `this` refers to `Example.` But it won't work if you do pass `Example.create` around without ensuring it's bound. For instance, `const create = Example.create; create(1, 2);` would fail with `new this(...)` but would work with `new Example(..)`.

Comment: I think the point is that the op don't want to specify the callee's name there for some weird reasons. Your code still have `Example` in the construction part.

Comment: Even without `new.target` you can still `if (!(this instanceof Example))return new Example(...arguments));` in your example.

Comment: @user202729 - Yeah, I originally wrote `if (!(this instanceof Example))` but then thought "Maybe they want to avoid the function name" and changed it...without twigging to the *other* `Example` in the code. Oops. :-)

Comment: Thank you for the response, and I do want to avoid the function name

Answer (score -1):

`if(!new.target)return new this[arguments.callee.name](...arguments);`

Comment: The community encourages adding explanations alongisde code, rather than purely code-based answers (see [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers)).